# synchronous communication between micro services using .net core

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, microservices

Based on my knowledge RabbitMQ provide a asynchronous communication, Sender doesn't wait for an response.

Direct Restful API Call from an one service to another is not a good practice

What are the possible way to  create synchronous communication between .net micro services using ?

A Sample Use case for the Problem

1. Micro service 1 called for saving employee information
2. Once Employee Information saved , from the Micro service 1 , Micro service 2  Called for Saving
   Employee  Payroll information
3. If Both of the Services are success, end User will get a success message otherwise end User will get
   failed message

Comment: Why isn’t direct API call good practice?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen If we make direct api call, then the micro service 1 is going to depend on micro service 2, and this will  make a traffic in network

Comment: But it has to depend on it anyway. If it needs to contact it then it depends on it. If it needs to contact it there’s going to be data passed back and forth. Why is that a bad thing? If you go for micro services they have to communicate somehow.

Comment: Why do you want to have a sync communication. Do you have specific requirements for that? If not you can actually implement the use-case you define with messages over rabbitmq. If you have specific sync communication requirement I have seen systems with over hundreds microservices using rest as the communication mechanism. Though I am not fan of rest communication you can go for it. But you should introduce service discovery, retry mechanism/circuit-breaker etc.